# Remove the file name from a messy path in a text file awk or sed

Tags: bash, sed, awk, perl

I have an xml file with many lines containing something like this:

```
Save="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\my files\1020\A54f\Drawing965.DWG" Module="0"
Save="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\my files\2706\gFgf0g4f\File1.PNG" Module="0"
Save="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\my files\8151\Test\Other.000" Module="0"
```

I would like to remove the file names and keep everything else. Like so:

```
Save="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\my files\1020\A54f\" Module="0"
Save="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\my files\2706\gFgf0g4f\" Module="0"
Save="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\my files\8151\Test\" Module="0"
```

The file names and folder names differ quite a bit but the depth to each file is the same. So basically erase file name after the 7th \

I hacked together this regex and it works but file names in other parts of the xml are being removed:

```
s/([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)\.([a-zA-Z0-9.]{3})$//g
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Perl way:

```
perl -pne 's/^.+\\\K[^"]+//' file
Save="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\my files\1020\A54f\" Module="0"
Save="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\my files\2706\gFgf0g4f\" Module="0"
Save="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\my files\8151\Test\" Module="0"
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/UEcLZZ/1)

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Priora: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

This will do it with GNU sed:

```
    sed 's/\(.*\)\\.*\..*\(" .*\)/\1\\\2/' your_file
```

The way it's working is as follows:

- I remember the stuff in between the above using `\(` and `\)` (these are
  capture groups).
- So the first capture group remembers as much as it can until it hits
  `\\.*\..*` - which is a literal backslash (note I had to escape it, so there
  are two) followed by any amount of characters and then a literal dot (this is part
  of the file name), followed by anything up to a `"` (which is where we begin
  the second capture group).
- The second capture group remembers everything following a double quote which
  precedes a space up to the end of the line.
- Then replace with the remembered content of the first capture group `\1`
  followed by a literal backslash followed by the remembered content of the
  second capture group and `\2`.

Once you've confirmed it does what you want, just add the `-i` to do the
substitution in-place:

```
    sed -i 's/\(.*\)\\.*\..*\(" .*\)/\1\\\2/' your_file
```

Input:

```
Save="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\my files\1020\A54f\Drawing965.DWG" Module="0"
Save="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\my files\2706\gFgf0g4f\File1.PNG" Module="0"
Save="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\my files\8151\Test\Other.000" Module="0"
```

Output:

```
Save="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\my files\1020\A54f\" Module="0"
Save="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\my files\2706\gFgf0g4f\" Module="0"
Save="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\my files\8151\Test\" Module="0"
```